# Programmaticaly add file as a link in C# project from inside visual studio add-in using EnvDTE API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project, envdte

I am working on a Visual Studio add-in which as part of its functionality has to modify existing C# project by adding (and removing) project items that are links to files outside project's tree.
I do not seem to find a way to insert a link to a file in a project using methods of ProjectItems interface exposed in EnvDTE namespace.
The alternative would be to manually modify project file and insert XML elements but I would prefer to avoid that and instead to use the interfaces provided by visual studio if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not possible using the automation model (EnvDTE) for C# (or VB.NET), only for C++. According to the [MSDN Docs about ProjectItems.AddFromFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile.aspx):

*FileName need not contain a full path as long as the file can be found. How a file is found depends on the programming language. In order to use pathless files in Visual Basic and Visual C#, for example, the files must be in the same directory as the project. If they are not, they are copied over. Visual C++ allows linking to files anywhere on the system.*

You can try using the VS native services (it's possible even from an add-in). Specifically, try the [IVsProject.AddItem method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsproject.additem.aspx) with [VSADDITEMOPERATION.VSADDITEMOP_LINKTOFILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.vsadditemoperation.aspx).

Comment: I was not aware of VS Shell services. Many thanks for pointing them out! I did try and was able to create a link that way.